# Fatal error.... LIBGDX

Tags: java, libgdx, rendering, box2d

I have an issue to launch fireball. 
when I launch fireball more than 10 swiftly, I got an error. 
especially, when my character becomes big which means to do redefine body.. 
I am still not sure why i got an error

and when I push space bar, fire() class will start, then in update, for loop will start. but here, when my character becomes big which go into defineBigMario , I got an error by launching fireball
I am not sure is this because update method does not afford multiple work? because in update method, there is two work to do defineBigMario method and launching fireball method .

> this is Firemethod. 
>   public class FireBall extends Sprite {

```
PlayScreen screen;
World world;
Array<TextureRegion> frames;
Animation fireAnimation;
float stateTime;
boolean destroyed;
boolean setToDestroy;
boolean fireRight;

Body b2body;
public FireBall(PlayScreen screen, float x, float y, boolean fireRight){
    this.fireRight = fireRight;
    this.screen = screen;
    this.world = screen.getWorld();
    frames = new Array<TextureRegion>();
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        frames.add(new TextureRegion(screen.getAtlas().findRegion("fireball"), i * 8, 0, 8, 8));
    }
    fireAnimation = new Animation(0.2f, frames);
    setRegion(fireAnimation.getKeyFrame(0));
    setBounds(x, y, 6 / MarioBros.PPM, 6 / MarioBros.PPM);
    defineFireBall();
}

public void defineFireBall(){
    BodyDef bdef = new BodyDef();
    bdef.position.set(fireRight ? getX() + 12 /MarioBros.PPM : getX() - 12 /MarioBros.PPM, getY());
    bdef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
    if(!world.isLocked())
    b2body = world.createBody(bdef);

    FixtureDef fdef = new FixtureDef();
    CircleShape shape = new CircleShape();
    shape.setRadius(3 / MarioBros.PPM);
    fdef.filter.categoryBits = MarioBros.FIREBALL_BIT;
    fdef.filter.maskBits = MarioBros.GROUND_BIT |
            MarioBros.COIN_BIT |
            MarioBros.BRICK_BIT |
            MarioBros.ENEMY_BIT |
            MarioBros.OBJECT_BIT;

    fdef.shape = shape;
    fdef.restitution = 1;
    fdef.friction = 0;
    b2body.createFixture(fdef).setUserData(this);
    b2body.setLinearVelocity(new Vector2(fireRight ? 2 : -2, 2.5f));
}

public void update(float dt){
    stateTime += dt;
    setRegion(fireAnimation.getKeyFrame(stateTime, true));
    setPosition(b2body.getPosition().x - getWidth() / 2, b2body.getPosition().y - getHeight() / 2);
    if((stateTime > 3 || setToDestroy) && !destroyed) {
        world.destroyBody(b2body);
        destroyed = true;
    }
    if(b2body.getLinearVelocity().y > 2f)
        b2body.setLinearVelocity(b2body.getLinearVelocity().x, 2f);
    if((fireRight && b2body.getLinearVelocity().x < 0) || (!fireRight && b2body.getLinearVelocity().x > 0))
        setToDestroy();
}

public void setToDestroy(){
    setToDestroy = true;
}

public boolean isDestroyed(){
    return destroyed;
}
```

}

> this is where I implement fire called Mario.class which is main character.
>
> public void update(float dt){
>           .....
>           setRegion(getFrame(dt));
>           if(timeToDefineBigMario)
>               defineBigMario();
>           if(timeToRedefineMario)
>               redefineMario();
>           for(FireBall  ball : fireballs) {
>               ball.update(dt);
>               if(ball.isDestroyed())
>                   fireballs.removeValue(ball, true);
>           }

```
}  
   public void fire(){
    fireballs.add(new FireBall(screen, b2body.getPosition().x, b2body.getPosition().y, runningRight ? true : false));
}
```

This is error message...

> #
>
> ## A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
>
> #
>
> ## EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000066bcbd0d, pid=7044, >tid=0x0000000000000b74
>
> #
>    # JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_112-b06) (build 1.8.0_112-
>    release-b06)
>    # Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.112-b06 mixed mode windows-amd64 
>    compressed oops)
>    # Problematic frame:
>    # C  [gdx-box2d64.dll+0xbd0d]
>    #
>    # Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client 
>    versions of Windows
>    #
>    # If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
>     #   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
>    # The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
>    # See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
>    #

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x0000000019b0a800):  JavaThread "LWJGL Application" 
 [_thread_in_native, id=2932, stack(0x000000001a770000,0x000000001a870000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x000000021a4e9380

Registers:
 RAX=0x000000021a4e9380, RBX=0x000000001a4a0780, RCX=0x000000001a4a0750, 
 RDX=0x00000000000000b8
 RSP=0x000000001a86e960, RBP=0x0000000000000006, RSI=0x000000001a4a0750,
 RDI=0x000000001a86ea20
 R8 =0x000000001a4a0750, R9 =0x0000000000000002, R10=0x0000000000000000, 
 R11=0x0000000000000001
 R12=0x0000000000000000, R13=0x00000000177f7a18, R14=0x000000001a86ec08, 
 R15=0x0000000019b0a800
 RIP=0x0000000066bcbd0d, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010202

Comment: Voting to close - this looks virtually identical to a previously closed question:
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/148863/a-fatal-error-has-been-detected-by-the-java-runtime-environment-in-libgdx
If you think the question can be made to be on-topic, edit the original question & request to have it opened.

Comment: page not found https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/148863/a-fatal-error-has-been-detected-by-the-java-runtime-environment-in-libgdx